# Xcode 5.1 storyboard file in IB , can't find file owner

Tags: xcode5, uistoryboard, facebook-ios-sdk

This is really confusing i build simple app using Xcode 5.1 storyboard builder 
i try to work with the simple Facebook [login tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.0#login-button) where it says:

- Select the View that represents the login button.
- In the Connections inspector, connect the delegate outlet to the File's Owner.

now i can't find any where in the IB something that looks like the "File's Owner."
i tried to follow those SO threads but still can't find it any where 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170393/connecting-file-owner-to-app-delegate) && [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636542/cocoa-how-to-connect-views-delegate-to-files-owner-in-storyboard-mode)

im attaching image that shows my Xcode , the arrow is the view object. 
so where is this "File's Owner" ?? 
[image]

Comment: in storyboard, View controller is handling delegates so assign to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Storyboard set delegate like this, whether it is view controller or table view controller.
anything to connect and required file's owner is maintained by view controller in storyboard.

[image: setting delegate]

or like this

[image: setting delegate]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer with screens

Answer (score 0):

File's Owner is the **View Controller** that is managing your view. So what you should do is assign your **delegates** to the view controller that is managing the **view** that you are using as the Login button.

From above image if **TableViewController** is managing your Login button then you should assign it as the **delegate**